# Make a checkbox visible when clicked on radio button in a gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

I have a Checkbox which is hidden at the page load.

I want to display this check box when I click on the Radio button which is in Gridview using jquery.

The checkbox is present outside the gridview.

Comment: please show us the generated html

Comment: some code will give a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<asp:Checkbox ID="chkOnHold" runat="server" visible="False" Text="On Hold"/>`

Well, when `visible="False"` is used, the control is ignored at the time of rendering & thus in turn, is not posted to the page which is displayed in the browser window.
(You can always check whether the control is present or not by pressing `F12` in your browser window. Then use `Ctrl+Mouse Click` to any adjacent element to the checkbox. You won't find the code corresponding to checkbox there.)

And as jquery works upon DOM or simply HTML, thus you can't access the checkbox as it isn't there. :)

You should better, use `AutoPostBack="true"` on RadioButton and then make the checkbox visible on `onChange` event of radioButton.
Having said that, if you still insist to achieve the task using jQuery, it can be done using AJAX & jQuery.

(Well, I'm not much aware how to achieve the same.)

Hope, I was helpful.

Comment: Thanks, This issue is completed. Now I want to check the textbox if some condition is correct.                                       $('#<%=divchkbox.ClientID %>').show();                             if (statId = 3) { $('#<%=divchkbox.ClientID %>').attr("checked","checked"); } This is not working.

Comment: @Sideways: Please enclose code in ```` to make it more clear & easily identifiable. Now, what is `statId` here?

Comment: It's a value. If it is 3 then the checkbox must be checked, else It should be unchecked.

Comment: Well, I can understand it's a value. :)
Are you using `$(document).ready();`???
Anyways, try this, by replacing the code in the first comment with:
`$('#<%=divchkbox.ClientID %>').show();   alert(statId);  if (statId == 3) { $('#<%=divchkbox.ClientID %>').attr("checked","checked"); alert(statID);   } ` And tell the result.

Comment: It showed a message box 2 times. In that message box "3" was there but the checkbox was not checked

Comment: @Sideways: Soory for the delay. Ok... so it means it's working... But are you using `$(document).ready();`??? In the mean time I'll check if there's some problem with checkbox code.

Comment: Thanks for your support but it is Working now. Will let you know if I have any other doubts.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function(){

     $('#chkOnHold').show(); 
});
```

The problem seems to be because of `visible="false"` .. This removes the control completely from the DOM..  Instead use `style="display:none"` to hide it

Comment: Actually the checkbox is out side the Grid.

Comment: @Sideways.. You should have given the HTML structure beforehand

Comment: The problem seems to be because of visible="false" .. This removes the control completely from the DOM..  Instead use style="display:none" to hide it

Comment: Yes, I Removed visible="false" and did used hide() and show() property in jQuery. Thanks for your help also.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple "onChange" for this case

Comment: I just want to know how to make a Textbox or Checkbox visible in jQuery.